# Why is my external css not working in a sub-directory folder?

Tags: html, jsp, web.xml

The files of my project are like this:

- Web Pages

  - WEB INF

    - View
  - CSS
  - User

    - account.jsp
    - error.jsp
    - login.jsp

All the `jsp pages` in the *view* folder load the css perfectly fine in the browser. But it does not for the pages in the sub-directory *User*. Instead of a relative path I tried an absolute path, it still doesn't work... Any idea of the roots cause of this issue? Been trying to figure it out for hours... Also if it can help, I recently made  changes to my web.xml... I doubt it has something to do with it but never know... All the codes below.

Account.jsp

```
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Site | <fmt:message key='UserAccount'/></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/account.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/header.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/footer.css">  
    </head>
```

Login.jsp

```
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Site | <fmt:message key='LoginRegister'/></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="web/css/login_register.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="web/css/header.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="web/css/footer.css"> 
    </head>
```

Error.jsp

```
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Site | Login Error</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/login_register.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/header.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/footer.css"> 
    </head>
```

Recent changes to the web.xml:

```
<jsp-property-group>
            <description>Handle the user console</description>
            <display-name>Jsp configuration for the user console </display-name>
            <url-pattern>/user/account.jsp</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/user/login.jsp</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/user/error.jsp</url-pattern>
            <include-prelude>/user/jspf/header.jspf</include-prelude>
            <include-coda>/user/jspf/footer.jspf</include-coda>
        </jsp-property-group>

    </jsp-config>
    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>Site User Administration</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Site User Administration</web-resource-name>
            <description/>
            <url-pattern>/user/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>

        <auth-constraint>
            <description/>
            <role-name>siteUser</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>


    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <realm-name>file</realm-name>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/user/login.jsp</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/user/error.jsp</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>


    <security-role>
        <description>Security for User</description>
        <role-name>mebzoneUser</role-name>
    </security-role>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using absolute paths, try adding a leading slash to your paths.

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/web/css/login_register.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/web/css/header.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/web/css/footer.css">
```

If you want relative paths within the child directory, then start with the parent directory using `..`

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/login_register.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/header.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/footer.css">
```

Comment: The absolute paths did not work. But the relative paths within the child directory did. Thanks a lot mate.

Answer (score -1):

My directory Path is `Prod/bootstrap/style.css` and I am using this path

```
script src="bootstrap-3.3.4-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"  type="text/css"
```

also tried this, well

```
script src="~/bootstrap-3.3.4-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"  type="text/css"
```

Also

```
script src="../bootstrap-3.3.4-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"  type="text/css"
```

It is working with pages placed in home directory,
but when I use pages in sub folder, then CSS failed to load at client-side.

ex.`Prod/Modules/Example.aspx`

Please Provide better solution for this problem.